# LEFT OUTER JOIN with count()?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider these tables:

**lists**:

```
id      name
1       somename
2       someothername
```

**leads**:

```
id  list
1   1
2   1
3   1
```

I currently have following query:

```
SELECT lists.*, count(leads.id)
FROM lists
LEFT OUTER JOIN leads ON lists.id =leads.list
```

Why is only the first list showing, instead of showing both?
List 1, and count = 3, and list 2 with count = 0?

Only the first list shows? Why is this?

Comment: You need `group by lists.id` at the end of your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group on the [`COUNT()` aggregation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count), you'll want to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    lists.id, count(leads.id)
FROM
    lists
    LEFT OUTER JOIN leads
        ON lists.id =leads.list
GROUP BY
    lists.id
```

Comment: Damn.. Thanks! Been wrapping my head around this for a while now!

Comment: Any idea, how to write the same query in linq to sql syntax - @newfurniturey

Answer (score 0):

You are Left Joining from `leads` to `lists`, which selects all values from `leads` (Which only has List 1) and only values from `lists` where there is a match. Instead: `LEFT OUTER JOIN lists ON lists.id =leads.list`